# Drinking alcohol while traveling home from a meeting

Tags: travel

If someone is traveling home from a meeting getting paid mileage and salary is it okay for them to stop at a bar/pub to drink alcohol?

Comment: are you asking if it is ok to drink and drive (i say never, myself), of what? I'm not sure why you'd ask what you're allowed to do after work finishes.are you asking if you can expense the alcohol, or expense the trip?

Comment: Unsure if the driver is drinking but pass. is but they are getting paid mileage to home and paid until they are home too?

Comment: What is "drinking but pass"?

Comment: Legally, no. Ethically, it's up to the person, but personally, I would not. Or I would just stop expensing when I enter the pub, i.e., that I would not expense the getting home from the pub part of the trip.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, heh, I had jumped ahead of myself. I had been considering drinking and driving.

Comment: @MaskedMan "but pass. is" == "but passenger is".

Answer (score 6):

> If someone is traveling home from a meeting getting paid mileage and
>   salary is it okay for them to stop at a bar/pub to drink alcohol?

Yes it is okay.

Getting a salary (rather than hourly) means you get paid the same no matter how long it takes you to get home.

And getting paid mileage means you can stop as many times as you like without changing the number of miles.

Comment: So they get paid for drinking on company time? our salary policy states they can leave early or come late if their time is put in to stay at their hours. What if they get hurt or in an accident its okay to be drinking on the job?

Comment: In some countries (France for example), accidents during travels between workplace and home are considered work accidents (and then the company has some legal duties). Local legislation should be checked, but stopping from a drink may relieve the company from their duties.

Comment: @Angie They're only "on the job" when they're working. Otherwise they could be considered on the job 24/7.  Don't make the mistake of tying mileage to wages. It's a reimbursement for the distance travelled, not for working. The work is covered by the salary. The mileage would apply if they went straight home or even caught a hotel for the night. Mileage is purely distance, not time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're driving then, no, it's not ok, otherwise it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You'd expense the mileage for the trip between the place of work and home.

What you shouldn't really do is expense the distance from home-pub-home if that pub is a diversion away from the route home.